# SQL to split Single row into multiple based on a count value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL statement that returns the following data:

```
FISCAL_ID    SECTION_ID      MAX_COUNT
1            1               3
1            2               1
2            1               2
2            2               2
```

How would I write SQL to return:

```
FISCAL_ID    SECTION_ID    VALUES
1            1             1
1            1             2
1            1             3
1            2             1
2            1             1
2            1             2
2            2             1
2            2             2
```

I am trying to generate a range of values for the max_count of each row in the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select fiscal_id, section_id, level as value
from test_data
connect by level <= max_count
and     fiscal_id = prior fiscal_id
and    section_id = prior section_id
and    prior sys_guid() is not null;
```